# Making an iframe fill the screen on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen-orientation

Hello as you can see from the pictures I have attached. I have managed to create a webpage which contains a video through an iframe. It rotates on mobile devices when portrait orientation is detected so the video always plays in landscape. I have this working now however my problem is when a mobile device is held in landscape mode the video is full screen and works lovely as you can see in the image below.

[MOBILE DEVICE HELD IN LANDSCAPE](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/image2.png)

When the device is held in portrait mode, (normal) the video rotates onto its side as it should however it does not fill the screen. The image that shows this can be found below.

[MOBILE DEVICE HELD IN PORTRAIT](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/image1.png)

All I need to do is make the video fill the screen when the device is held in portrait, just like it does in landscape.

My code is below:

***CSS***

```
<style>
* {
height: 100%; width: 100%; top: -20px; left: 0px;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
body {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
}
</style>
```

***HTML***

```
<body>
       <div><iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/qnca9gdlv5?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></div><script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

[ALSO HERE IS A LIVELINK TO THE OFFENDING PAGE SO YOU CAN VIEW THE SOURCE YOURSELF](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/beach.html)

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the problem, but your links are down. Could you find a better host or [put your code into a JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Rather than trying to set the rotation for the `iframe`, why don't you use absolute positioning to size it?

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/">
```

Doing it like this tells the browser just to make the content fill the screen, and you don't have to handle rotation or anything else.

Comment: the only reason is that there will be more content outside of the iframe eventually, this will be underneath and I don't want the iframe to obscure the other content. So if I rotate the whole page this content will not be hidden.